# Error while running npm run dev command in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babel-loader

I am new to React.js and i am trying to setup simple react application locally using webpack.
while running the npm run dev command i m getting below error.

Error getting in command prompt after running **npm run dev**

```
F:\ReactApp\react-webpack>npm run dev


> react-webpack@1.0.0 dev F:\ReactApp\react-webpack
> webpack -wd

error: option '-d, --devtool <value>' argument missing

npm ERR! code ELIFECCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! react-webpack@1.0.0 dev: `webpack -wd`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the react-webpack@1.0.0 dev script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\nilesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T08_33_31
_702Z-debug.log
```

Below is code in package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -wd"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Below is code for the webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry : './js/app.js',
    output : {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'

    },
    module :{

        loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader:'babel-loader'
             }
        ]
    }
};
```

Code in app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here my .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets":[
        "react",
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

I have already install latest version of node.js

Thanks in Advance

Nilesh Kulkarni

Comment: Error message is telling you that you're using `webpack -d` without specifying an argument after `-d`. You can find a list of valid argument value [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Comment: Thank you very much i have added the value for devtool  in webpack.config.js file but no luck....still facing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you're missing a value for the -d (--devtool) argument. You can find a list of valid values on [this list](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). You can add this directly to your webpack config as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: 'source-map' // or any other valid value here
    ...
};
```

You only need to have a value for devtool in the config if you want to use a value, similarly you only need to use the `-d` argument in the CLI if you are going to pass a value through the CLI. If you don't want to use a devtool, remove it from your webpack config and change your dev script to `webpack -w`. However, for development, you'll likely want sourcemaps, so I'd recommend using `devtool: 'source-map'` (you'll still want to change your dev script to `webpack -w`).

Comment: Hi i have added the value for devtool  as none but still facing the same error, but when i am updating my value for scripts in package.json file as  ```webpack -d``` instead of ```webpack -wd``` it shows no error in command prompt but it does not create the bundle.js file

Comment: Here is webpack.config. js file. Now i am facing the same error. I am using (none), is this correct syntax for none
```const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    devtool :  ' ',
    entry : './js/app.js',
    output : {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module :{
        loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader:'babel-loader'
             }
        ]
    }
};```

Comment: Updated my answer. In summary, the correct syntax for (none) would be to omit the `devtool` value from your config and change your dev script to `webpack -w`

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify devtool, either by using `-d devtools` or by putting

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: 'source-map'
    ...
};
```

in your `webpack.config.js`.

If you chose to change the `webpack.config.js` file you don't need the `-d` option, if you use `-d` you must specify an argument after or it will throw an error.

Comment: Below is webpack.config.js file

I am using (none), is this correct syntax for none

`const path = require('path');
module.exports = {

    devtool: ' ',
    entry : './js/app.js',
    output : {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'

    },
    module :{

        loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader:'babel-loader'
             }
        ]
    }
};
`

Comment: Yes finally it worked, i have updated webpack.config.js file as ```devtool: 'source-map'``` but along with i have also updated the version on babel-core and babel-loader as i have faced issue with the versioning for babel-core i have used ```npm install babel-core --save-dev``` and for babel-loader i have used ```npm install babel-loader@7.1.4```   Thank you very much for your help..it worked